# Java Calculadora con Do While()

Tags: java

Saludos a todos y de antemano gracias por su ayuda.
Soy nuevo en esto de Java y estoy practicando con Do While() por mi cuenta asi que intente realizar una calculadora con el siguiente codigo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Calc2 {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    String yn;
    do{
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(" Enter first  # : ");
        int num1=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" Enter second # : "); 
        int num2=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" Selec Symbol (+, -, *, /): ");
        String sym=scan.next();
        int res;    
        switch(sym){

       case "+": res=num1 + num2;
         System.out.println(" Addition is :"+res);
         System.out.println();
     break; 
       case "-": res= num1-num2;
         System.out.println(" Substraction is :"+res);
         System.out.println();
     break;
       case "*": res=num1*num2;
         System.out.println(" Multiplication is:"+res);
         System.out.println();
     break;
       case "/": res=num1/num2;
         System.out.println(" Division is :"+res);
     System.out.println();
         break;
       default: System.out.println(" Invalid Symbol ");
     System.out.println();
         break;
         }
         System.out.print(" Do you want to continue ? [y = Yes, n = No ]: ");
     yn=scan.next();
    }while(yn.equal("y")││yn.equals("Y"));
 }
}
```

pero al ejecutarlo solo me da 100 lineas de error por ejemplo:

> Calc2.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0000'  ■i m p o r t   j a v
>   a . u t i l . S c a n n e r ;
>                  ^ Calc2.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0000'  ■i m p o r t   j a v a . u t i l . S c a n n e r ;
>                            ^ Calc2.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0000'  ■i m p o r t   j a v a . u t i l . S c a n n e r ;
>                                      ^ Calc2.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u0000'  ■i m p o r t   j a v a . u t i l . S c a n n e r
>   ;
>                                                      ^ Calc2.java:2: error: illegal character: '\u0000'
>
> ^ Calc2.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'  c l a s s   C a l
>   c 2   { ^ Calc2.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'  c l a s s 
>   C a l c 2   {
>               ^ Calc2.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u0000'

esto es solo una muestra pero ya se podran imaginar el resto ya que es similar. Les agradeceria me pudieran ayudar a entender donde esta mi error. Gracias

Comment: Trata de guardar el archivo con codificación UTF-8 con BOM o ASCII a ver si se resuelve el problema, no es de código, es que tienes caracteres inválidos para el analizador sintáctico de Java

Comment: Hola César Barrios, bienvenido a [es.so] ahora me pondré a revisar el código, pero antes de nada quería darte la enorabuena, porque este podría ser un ejemplo de una muy buena "Primera publicación" Dices lo que quieres hacer, con el código necesario, un error concreto y demuestras que lo has intentado.

Comment: Imagino que será algo como lo que dice @NaCl pero también te hago una recomendación bastante sencilla, pero muy util: En la útima linea del código, en vez de: `while(yn.equal("y")││yn.equals("Y"));` podrías poner esto: `while(yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));` lo cual quiere decir que le dará lo mismo que sea mayúscula que minúscula. Además si te fijas te debería dar error de sintaxis, ya que en uno pones `yn.equal` y en el otro `yn.equals`. Ya que `String.equal()` salvo que en java9 hayan metido ese metodo, creo que no existe

Comment: \u0000 traducido a Java es null, pero normalmente si fuese un error de puntero te pondría el mítico java.null.pointerException. Yo tuve problemas parecidos en Python con tildes y letras que no eran del alfabeto latino, tuve que poner la codificación en UTF-8.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su repuesta, lo guarde como UTF-8 y ahora me muestra esto :

Calc2.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
´╗┐import java.util.Scanner;
 ^
Calc2.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bf'
´╗┐import java.util.Scanner;
  ^

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por su aporte, les comento que mi error fue guardarlo como Codificacion diferente a ANSI, al ya guardarlo de esta forma ya funciona correctamente.  Nuevamente gracias a todos esto ya se resolvio!!!

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la codificacion a la hora de guardar, puedes cambiarlo de la siguiente manera.

Click derecho sobre la carpeta del proyecto ->

[image: Imagen propiedades]

[image: Imagen 2]

Cámbialo a `UTF-8`, eso debería funcionar.